# Passing a variable from one page to another using PHP

Tags: php

Does anyone know what's wrong with the code below that prevents me from printing in `File2.php` the variable `$myusername` from `File1.php`.

I simply wanna print the variable `$myusername`, or if you know any other way of how to pass that variable that would be very helpful for me.

Here is my example:

**File1.php**

```
<?php 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 

function getusername() 
{ 
   return $myusername;    
} 
?>
```

**File2.php**

```
<?php 
require_once('File1.php'); 
getusername(); 
?>
```

Comment: try reading for sessions

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot print"? Can you paste here any error messages you get?

Answer (score 4):

I would advocate utilizing [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

> Session support in PHP consists of a way to preserve certain data
>   across subsequent accesses. This enables you to build more customized
>   applications and increase the appeal of your web site.
>
> A visitor accessing your web site is assigned a unique id, the
>   so-called session id. This is either stored in a cookie on the user
>   side or is propagated in the URL.
>
> The session support allows you to store data between requests in the
>   $_SESSION superglobal array. When a visitor accesses your site, PHP
>   will check automatically (if session.auto_start is set to 1) or on
>   your request (explicitly through session_start() or implicitly through
>   session_register()) whether a specific session id has been sent with
>   the request. If this is the case, the prior saved environment is
>   recreated.

**File1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myusername'] = (isset($_POST['myusername']) ? $_POST['myusername'] : '');
?>
```

**File2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['myusername'];
?>
```

You will also notice that in the `File1.php` code provided, the `$_SESSION['myusername']` declaration is checking if the value was provided first.  If it was then set the session variable to that value, otherwise set it to empty.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare `$myusername` as global when you are trying to access it from within function, you also need to print is somehow (e.g. `echo`) ;)

```
File1.php
<?php 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 

function getusername() 
{ 
   global $myusername; // declare as global
   return $myusername;    
} 
?>

File2.php
<?php 
    require_once('File1.php'); 
    echo getusername();        // echo value
?>
```

Read more: [PHP Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). 
You could also pass it via [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Comment: Are you sure this example works?? I tried the same one copy paste the code still it dosnt show anything.

Comment: I've edited my answer, it wasn't showing anything because there were no `echo`.

Comment: isnt global declaration outside of function?? as it is in other programming languages???

Comment: It is working, maybe you want to use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`? Try replacing `$_POST` with `$_GET` and then access your file via browser like this: `File2.php?myusername=hello-world`. Works for me :)

Comment: You need to use `global` in this case, because you are trying to access global scope variable. Without it you would just access local scope (inside function) variable, which doesn't exist. There is a good link at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: if i try this way $myusername='hello' instead of $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];  , then it prints hello, why it is not printing the value which it takes from the textfield??

Comment: i cannot log in to chat, cz i dont have enought reputation :S

Comment: It is showing `hello` because you assigned it to `$myusername`. Try this: `$myusername = $_GET['myusername'];` Read my answer and comments again, you should read manual (as I have pointed in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

By session.

File1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $_POST['myusername'];
```

File2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['myusername'];
```